# Integrating pinax-notifications failed in django app

Tags: python, django, notifications, pinax

Im working with `django-1.10` and would like to implement some notification behaviour for my application using `pinax-notifications-4.0`.

I am following the [quickstart](https://pinax-notifications.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for including this to the `INSTALLED_APP`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "pinax.notifications",
    # ...
]
```

then and the [usage](https://pinax-notifications.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/) guide.

First is to create the notice type in **heat/handler.py**

```
from pinax.notifications.models import NoticeType
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_noop as _

def create_notice_types(sender, **kwargs): 
    NoticeType.create(
        "heat_detection", 
        _("Heat Detected"), 
        _("you have detected a heat record")
    )
```

Secondly call the handler to create notices after the application is migrated. **heat.apps.py**

```
from .handlers import create_notice_types

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

class HeatConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'heat'

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(create_notice_types, sender=self)
```

finally include the appconfig to the **heat.__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'heat.apps.HeatConfig'
```

but when trying to run these:

```
python manage.py makemigrations pinax.notifications
```

I got this error: `RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Then i try to change the `pinax.notifications` to `pinax-notifications` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. The server yield me this error:  `ImportError: No module named pinax-notifications`

**How to make this work?**

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.sites` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: i added and i change the `pinax.notifications` to `pinax` and now its working i do not know why yet but the docs clearly states that `pinax.notifications`

Comment: Seen that also.

Comment: but before that i commented the `default_app_config = 'heat.apps.HeatConfig'` in my `heat.__init__.py` and when trying to uncomment it and try runserver i have an error `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: You can just use the entire dotted path in your `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of using `default_app_config`

Comment: you mean i have to directry write the `heat.apps.HeatConfig` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131399/discussion-between-evans-murithi-and-shift-n-tab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solved it by changing the heat.apps.py file

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
from .handlers import create_notice_types

class HeatConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'heat'

    def ready(self):        
        post_migrate.connect(create_notice_types, sender=self)
```

to this.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class HeatConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'heat'

    def ready(self):
        from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
        from .handlers import create_notice_types

        post_migrate.connect(create_notice_types, sender=self)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I also encountered this problem and found, as Roel Delos Reyes previously did, that changing the app-name to `pinax` (instead of `pinax.notifications` as the documentation very-clearly states) appears to have solved the problem.

When I made this change, `makemigrations` found all of the migrations.

I'm actually using both "pinax.notifications" and "pinax.templates" (as the documentation for notifications recommends), and I see that *both* sets of documentation clearly specify `pinax.<something>`. I can't explain it ... how could the documentation be *that* wrong?  Twice?

(I'm using Django 1.19 instead of 2.0 for other unrelated reasons, but I don't think that matters.)

Anyhow – "this worked."  HTH.™

**Important Edit:** I subsequently found that *both* `pinax` *and* `pinax.notifications` are needed in `INSTALLED_APPS`.  Without the latter, `migrate` would not *apply* all of the migrations.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'pinax',
   'pinax.notifications', 
   ...
   ]
```

I also opened *(and have since closed)* a trouble-ticket to this effect in the project on GitHub, so please refer to that site, as well.